# Laravel - Store function not working using routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I am having trouble when inputting data and figuring out why my data is not being stored into the database. I have tried to use the resources route and my custom route code, but it seems still nothing works. Clicking submit just seems to refresh the page with no errors to show

And here is my form :

```html
<div class="container">
    <form action="{{ route('lessons.store') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        
        <input class="d-none" name="courses_id" value="{{$course->id}}">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="name">Title</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong></span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="status">Status</label><br>
                    <select name="status" id="status" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('status') }}" required>
                        <option value="Active">Active</option>
                        <option value="Deactive">Deactive</option>
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('status'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('status') }}</strong></span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Subject : </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-12">                                
                <textarea id="editor"  name="subject" class="w-100 form-control{{$errors->has('subject') ? ' is-invalid' : ''}}" id="subject" rows="3" value="{{old('subject')}}"></textarea>
                @if ($errors->has('subject'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('subject') }}</strong></span>
                @endif                                
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer pb-0">
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Discard</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>                
</div>
```

My store function in SubjectCourse :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);

    $courseSubject = new CourseSubject([
        'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
        'subject' => $request->get('subject'),            
    ]);

    if($courseSubject->save()) {
        return \App::make('redirect')->back()->refresh()->with('flash_success', 'Success!');
    } else {
        return \App::make('redirect')->back()->refresh()->with('flash_error', 'Error!');
    }

}
```

And here is my routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Teacher']], function () {    
    Route::get('/t', function() {
        return view('dashboard.teacher.teacher');
    });

    Route::resource('t/courses', 'CoursesController');
    Route::get('t/courses', 'CoursesController@index')->name('courses.index');

    Route::resource('t/courses/lesson', 'SubjectCourses')->only('store');
    Route::get('t/courses/{id}/lessons', 'SubjectCourses@index')->name('lessons.index');
    Route::post('/t/courses/lessons/add', 'SubjectCourses@store')->name('lessons.store');


});
```

Again, I'm not getting any error messages at all, it's just that the submission button does nothing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your validation. Your field name is name but you are validating it as title in your controller. Change this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('title') }}" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in user store function:

```
$courseSubject = CourseSubject::create([
    'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
    'title' => $request->get('title'),
    'status' => $request->get('status'),
    'subject' => $request->get('subject'),            
]);
```

Dont use instance and use `CourseSubject::create` instead `new CourseSubject`.
Currect the name of feild in your controller or blade. They are not match.